# In VueJS, how to access object returned by external api

Tags: express, vue.js, captcha

I have added the hcaptcha widget to my login component using this package: https://github.com/hCaptcha/vue-hcaptcha. The challenge works as expected on the front end.

The response object as viewed in the network tab includes a token and looks like this:

```
expiration: 120
generated_pass_UUID: "P0_eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbG...O9U"
pass: true
```

My question is how to pass that token with my email and password when I submit the login form.

Normally, I am using axios to make an explicit api call and I can define a variable like:
`let response = axios.get('/whater_api')`
and then use `response.data` to access whatever comes back. But I can't see how to do that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `@verify="onVerify"` event? it seems the result is emitted on that event, try to add methods `onVerify` on your vue instance like below:

```
methods: {
  onVerify: function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  } 
}
```

if it does return the response, you can make an object for the token, your email and password and the rest is just as usual.